How to Install Sitecore 10.4 using script to only install core, master, core and experience form db?
I have a requirement to install Sitecore 10.4 on dev machine without installing extra DBs, only Solr, web, core, master and Experience forms. No xConnect is needed.

For your requirement, where you want to set up only the master, web, core, and Experience Forms without xConnect, the XM Single or Scaled topology package should work here. This setup will allow you to work with the core Sitecore content management and delivery environments without the additional Experience Platform services, like xConnect or xDB.
You can find the compatibility in the XM scaled package here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/104/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-xp-feature-compatibility-in-xm-scaled-packages.html#incompatible
And you can download it from here.
Sitecore Download options
Hope this helps.

I am using XP0 package and it installs many databases - so I need to use XM Single?

Thank you so much and it worked!  one more question, i need to use the existing certificate instead of creating self-signed certificate, how do I do that?

This will help. https://jesuissitecore.com/2020/10/15/install-a-ssl-certificat-to-your-sitecore-site/

I know how to change it after installation, I was wondering if it is possible to make change to install script to use existing certificate.

Yes, I guess you need to check the XP0.json file see how GetCertificateThumbprint is bound and you need to modify it here. Hope this helps.

You can download packages for XM Single or XM Scaled Topology from the Sitecore 10.4 download link as below.
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/104/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_104
This will only setup master,web, core and experience database on your local setup.
Note: With XM Single toplology you will have one environment that will behave both as CM and CD, whereas in case of XM Scaled topology you will have separate instance for both CM as well as CD.
Update:
In order to disable CD installation on XM Scaled Package, you can remove the following configuration from XM1-SingleDeveloper.json file.

Hope this helps!!!

I do not see XM Single for onprem package

@John You can download the package for XM Scaled and then once downloaded you can disable the CD installation. I will update the answer above on how we can disable that. Hope that works!!!

if I disable CD, does it means on my dev box I do not have the functionality of CD? or after the installation all function will be presented?

@John Basically on local we can have one environment that can act as both CM as well as CD. You can manage the role on a particular instance using role:define setting..You can find more details on the same here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/platform-administration-and-architecture/define-the-server-role.html#specify-the-server-role.

In case you would like to have separate Content Management(CM) and Content Delivery(CD) instaces, you can choose the XM scaled topology and that will install both these instances for you. Hope that helps!!!
